# Subtracting a date from SYSDATE in ORACLE

Tags: date, oracle10g, datediff, sysdate

Subtracting a date from `SYSDATE` gives negative results:

```
select floor(SYSDATE - dateemb) from pilote;

FLOOR(SYSDATE-DATEEMB)
----------------------
                -29126
                -29137
                -29522
```

any solution to this?

table pilote:

```
Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------

 NUMPIL                                    NOT NULL NUMBER
 NOMPIL                                             VARCHAR2(25)
 ADRPIL                                             VARCHAR2(25)
 SALAIRE                                            NUMBER
 COMMISSION                                         NUMBER
 DATEEMB                                            DATE
```

data used:

```
NUMPIL   NOMPIL    ADRPIL   SALAIRE   COMMISSION     DATEEMB
------- --------  -------- --------   ----------    ---------
1333    FEDOI      NANTES   24000      0            01-MAR-92                           

6589    DUVAL      PARIS    18600     5580          12-MAR-92

7100    MARTIN     LYON     15600     16000         01-APR-93
```

Comment: Please post the schema of the `pilote` table and the data in the three rows used for the example.

Comment: Your question is strange. Your SQL says `- hire_date`, but your table example says `- DATEEMB`. Can you clarify and show sample data from the table?

Comment: If hire_date is in the future then your query is correct. If you don't ever want negative numbers then use abs(), but as @Codo said - some data would be a big help.

Comment: @KenWhite, yes you're right am sorry, it's "dateemb" i was translating from french.

Comment: @meno - still no data in your question.

Comment: Well, that's half of what you were asked for. :-) Now can you supply the data you used to show the results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058/what-is-the-difference-between-oracles-yy-and-rr-date-mask) indicates that there is a date format in Oracle that would make your year 92 into 2092 (i.e in the future) rather than 1992 as probably intended. If this format has been used to insert your data with a 2-digit year then your dates are all wrong, if you write them out in full you should be able to confirm that. The solution would be to fix the data at the point it is created and use 4-digit years.

Comment: solution was to re-enter the dates with the full year format.