# Oracle TimeStamp update/insert year interpret

Tags: sql, database, oracle, timestamp

Am I right in thinking within Oracle, if I were to do a an Update/Insert to a TimeStamp column  with the following...

```
UPDATE tblBlah set TimeStampColumn = to_timestamp('01-01-99 12:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YY HH:MI AM')
```

Oracle would interpret the year as an already occurred year, 1999 as opposed to a future year 2099 ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to try than to ask here? `SELECT to_timestamp('01-01-99 12:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YY HH:MI AM') FROM DUAL`

Comment: [What is the difference between oracle's 'yy' and 'rr' date mask?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058/what-is-the-difference-between-oracles-yy-and-rr-date-mask)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`YY` will take the last two digits and overwrite those of the current year.

```
select to_timestamp('01-01-99 12:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YY HH:MI AM') from dual
-->
January, 01 2099 00:00:00+0000
```

Use `RR` instead:

```
select to_timestamp('01-01-99 12:00 AM', 'MM/DD/RR HH:MI AM') from dual
-->
January, 01 1999 00:00:00+0000
```

`RR` will:

> Given a year with 2 digits, returns a year in the next century if the
>   year is <50 and the last 2 digits of the current year are >=50;
>   returns a year in the preceding century if the year is >=50 and the
>   last 2 digits of the current year are <50.

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/10781/1)