# Oracle RR date format in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008, oracle11g

I have an Oracle SQL script that I'm converting to run in MS SQL Server. The script has the `to_date` function in it and uses the `RR` date format. Here's the function:

```
to_date('07-AUG-14','DD-MON-RR')
```

I'm going to use the MS SQL Server function `CONVERT` like this

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, '07-AUG-14', num)
```

where `num` is the code of the format I need.

What code should I use in MS SQL Server to get the same type of functionality as the Oracle `RR` format?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7183924/2363712

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a U.S. datetime conversion, you can use:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, '07-AUG-14', 10)
--                             ^^
```

For other cultures, *style* (the 3rd argument) will differ; but *style* needs to be a **Without century (yy)** value for your purpose.

The semantics of Oracle's `RR` date format apply to SQL Server's `yy` date styles too.  [*CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)* (for SQL Server 2008)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.100).aspx) on MSDN explains...

> By default, SQL Server interprets two-digit years based on a cutoff year of 2049. That is, the two-digit year 49 is interpreted as 2049 and the two-digit year 50 is interpreted as 1950.

...and lists the numeric values for the **Without century (yy)** date styles.

(For reference, another SO answer explains the equivalent [semantics of Oracle's `RR` date format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19061/1810429).)

You can more broadly confirm the default semantics of SQL Server's (U.S.) `yy` date style with the following queries...

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '07-AUG-14', 10)
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '07-AUG-49', 10)
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '07-AUG-50', 10)
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '07-AUG-51', 10)
```

..., which yield...

```
2014-08-07 00:00:00.000 -- This century assumed.
2049-08-07 00:00:00.000 -- This century assumed.
1950-08-07 00:00:00.000 -- Last century assumed.
1951-08-07 00:00:00.000 -- Last century assumed.
```

...with a default **two-digit year cutoff** configuration.  (`yy` date styles for other cultures should behave similarly.)